# Median sort a list in unordered fashion

Tags: python, sorting, median, bisection

What's the best way of sorting a python list in an unordered fashion according to the median of value positions in the list?

Suppose:

`a = [1, 3 ,6, 7, 10, 12, 17]`

I'm looking for this:

`a = [1, 17, 7, 3, 12, 6, 10]`

Meaning, the list now looks like `[start, end, mid, first_half_mid, second_half_mid, ...]`

edit: To clarify further, I'm looking for a way to keep bisecting the list until it covers the whole range!

edit2: Another example to illustrate the problem

input:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

desired output:

`[1, 10, 6, 3, 9, 2, 5, 8, 4, 7]`

Comment: When you say "accurate" you mean "best" right? Also, please provide what you have tried.

Comment: Yeah, meant "best"! Perhaps I couldn't convey my meaning due to number of down votes, but in fact, it's a problem that have many optimization use cases. So far, I've looked into bisection and median functions, however, those are suited for searching rather than sorting. I believe what I need to figure out is how to do it recursively so that I can get the right result.

Comment: Indeed, it's an interesting question (+1). But i don't understand your output list, shouldn't it be: `[1,17,7, 3,12,10]` - as `12` is the `end` on the second iteration?

Comment: Thanks Max. That's correct too. The idea is keep doing the bisection until it covers the whole range. Perhaps it should it's even more correct like this `[7, 3, 12, 1, 10, 6, 17]` which means `[result of first bisection, result of second bisection, ...]` It's also necessary both sides go in parallel. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Yasin, yes, it makes lots of sense! I would suggest you to open a new question and add a `numpy` tag to it (if using numpy is an option for you) - this would attract numpy specialists. I'm pretty sure there is a very effective numpy/scipy solution for this task, but i don't know it yet. PS would you please ping me from this question with the link to a new one  (in case you decide to open it)?

Comment: Sure, I'll do that soon if this doesn't get answered. What do you suggest for the title of new question? "Sorting lists in bisection/median order"?

Comment: I thought your input list is already sorted, isn't it? It might be important...

Comment: Perhaps "sorting" is not the right word for it. How about "ordering"? What the input list contains (whether sorted or not) does not really matter. This is more about ordering the elements index in a bisection fashion.

Comment: `Numpy: ordering the elements in a bisection fashion` - sounds good to me

Comment: "best" by what criterion?

Comment: @Yasin I think to help clarify what you would want to do here, you could provide a longer example (perhaps 3 bisections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** consider left element as a middle if the length of the list is an even numer

```
def f(a):
    # take left middle element for even-length lists
    mid = len(a)//2 if len(a)%2 else len(a)//2-1
    # take len(a)//2 as a middle element 
    #mid = len(a)//2 
    if len(a) <= 2:
        return a
    elif(len(a) == 3):
        return a[[0,-1,mid]]
    else:
        return np.append(a[[0,-1,mid]], f(np.delete(a, [0,len(a)-1,mid])))
```

Output:

```
In [153]: f(a)
Out[153]: array([ 1, 17,  7,  3, 12,  6, 10])
```

**OLD answer:**

here is one of many possible solutions:

```
import numpy as np

def f(a):
    if len(a) <= 2:
        return a
    elif(len(a) == 3):
        return a[[0,-1,len(a)//2]]
    else:
        return np.append(a[[0,-1,len(a)//2]], f(np.delete(a, [0,len(a)-1,len(a)//2])))

a = np.array([1, 3 ,6, 7, 10, 12, 17])

In [114]: a
Out[114]: array([ 1,  3,  6,  7, 10, 12, 17])

In [115]: f(a)
Out[115]: array([ 1, 17,  7,  3, 12, 10,  6])
```

PS about last two numbers in the result list/array - the question is what is the middle index for the 4-elements list?

What is the middle element for `[3,6,10,12]` list? In my solution it would be `10` (index: `4//2 == 2`)

Comment: Thanks Max :) This one works great too! In the case of having such even lists `[3, 6, 10, 12]` either 6 or 10 would be chosen, but often it would be the left element. Which one does your solution choose?

Comment: you are welcome! :) My solution would chose `10` as `4//2 == 2`

Comment: Great! Do you think there is a way to only consider `start` and `end` on the first iteration and on the next iterations it only results the bisected result? It will be really similar to @Jasper solution with the exception that the start and end indices would now come at the beginning of the resulted list.

Comment: @Yasin, can you post a desired output list? i'm not quite sure that i got your idea

Comment: Sure. As an example, try running `[1, 3 ,6, 7, 10, 12, 17]` with Jasper's method. It will result `[7, 3, 12, 1, 6, 10, 17]` which is fine and correctly bisecting. The only thing I'm missing here is that resulted list does not start with first and last elements in the original list. So I would only need to relocate those two elements to the beginning of the list and it will be `[1, 17, 7, 3, 12, 6, 10]` which is what I'm after. Your method takes care of this first and last elements, however it would be great if it only does that in the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a breadth-first task, so I used a Queue:

```
# from queue import Queue, Empty # python 3
from Queue import Queue, Empty   # python 2

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
accu = []
q = Queue()
# a.sort()     # if it isn't already sorted.

def do_it(l):  # whatever a precise name might be...

    global accu
    accu = [l[0], l[-1]]
    q.put(l[1:-1])             # Add first and last element, start with rest of list.
    try:
        while True:

            l = q.get_nowait()

            if not l:
                continue

            print("working on {}".format(l))
            middle = l[len(l)//2]
            left = l[:len(l)//2]
            right = l[len(l)//2+1:]

            accu.append(middle)
            q.put(left)
            q.put(right)

            print("added {}, todo: {} // {}".format(middle, left, right))
    except Empty:
        pass



print(a)
do_it(a)
print(accu)
```

Result:

```
[1, 10, 6, 4, 8, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2]
```

I don't quite get why 10 is before 6 in your comment.

Comment: I think OP wants something different. The resulting list should be either `[ 1, 17,  7,  3, 12, 10,  6]` or `[ 1, 17,  7,  3, 12, 6,  10]`, depending on definition of the `middle` element

Comment: OP seems to differ :) (I implemented it according to the comment, always taking the "middle" element...)

Comment: Brilliant! In fact both methods are correct according to the nature of the problem. It was hard deciding between which one to choose! I need to fix the example though to reflect the issue better. Regarding this solution, I had to do `from multiprocessing import Queue` instead of `from queue import Queue` since this one was giving me an import error.

Comment: The module is called `Queue` in Python 2

Comment: @Jasper, you're right! I didn't notice that the desired output was changed in the comments

Comment: `from six.moves.queue import Queue` would be compatible with both Python versions at the cost of additional module - [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/)

Comment: @Jasper, there seems to be an issue somewhere in the snippet. When I run it on `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, I get `[6, 3, 9, 2, 5, 8, 10, 1]` which is missing two of the elements. Any idea why?

Comment: You should be able to track it down with the print statements. I guess some rounding problems?

Comment: The print shows that 4 and 7 are on the to-do list but they don't really get processed. `added 5, todo: [4] // []` and `added 8, todo: [7] // []`

Comment: Yep, they were added to the queue but never processed. Forgot to loop.

Comment: @Yasin, can you update your question with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` as input list and also post an expected/desired output list?

Comment: Sweet! Thanks @Jasper. MaxU, updated the post with the better example. Jasper's solution is very close to the desired output, it just misses the first and last elements on the original list showing up at the beginning of the output list.

Comment: That's a very special case, right (putting first and last elements of source list as first and second element in result?)?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'd just do a post-process on it and it should be good. Thanks again :)

Comment: Added a "pre-processing" step

Comment: Hmm, the update not quite working now! I'm getting this `[1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 6, 4, 8, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2]`

Comment: Remove the `:` in the initialization of the accumulator: `accu = [l[0], l[-1]]`

Comment: The thing is, now the output is farther away from the desired one `[1, 10, 6, 4, 8, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2]`! previously I was getting `[6, 3, 9, 2, 5, 8, 10, 1, 4, 7]` which is a lot closer but just missing the first and last elements in the beginning of the list!